# Shell function to test if a file exists in bash

Tags: linux, loops, file, terminal

I am very new to anything terminal/linux related. I need to create a shell function that checks if a file exits (multiple files). Needs to include if/else, do/while, and for.

This is what I have but I am super lost

```sh
#!/bin/bash


for FILE in "$@"

do
    if [ -f $FILE ];
    then
        echo "'$FILE' exists"

    else
        echo "'$FILE' does not exist."
    break
fi
done
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Make that `if [ -f "$FILE" ]`.

Comment: The `;` after the line with `if` is redundant.

Comment: The `break` is redundant.